# TypeScript generic constraints to multiple primitive types

Tags: typescript

Given this function:

```
myFunc(object: string | null): string | null {}
```

I would like this function to be of return type `string` when the object is `string`, and return type of `string | null` when the object is of type `string | null`.

I have tried:

```
myFunc<T extends string | null>(object: T): T {
    return "returnValue"; //Type '"returnValue"' is not assignable to type 'T'.
}
```

and

```
myFunc<T extends string & null>(object: T): T {
    return "returnValue"; //Type '"returnValue"' is not assignable to type 'T'.
}
```

Both produce the same compile error. I have not found the correct syntax to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't believe I'm actually going to suggest overloads, as I spend a goodly portion of my time explaining how most of them can be avoided... but an overload would be a good way to model this!

```
class Example {
    myFunc(obj: string): string;
    myFunc(obj: string | null): string | null;
    myFunc(obj: string | null): string | null {
        return "returnValue";
    }
}

function test(a: string | null, b: string) {
    const example = new Example();

    // resultA: string | null
    const resultA = example.myFunc(a);

    // resultB: string
    const resultB = example.myFunc(b);
}
```

In the above example, the return types are mapped to the input types, so `resultA` and `resultB` have the expected types, *provided you are running with strict null checks enabled*.